# Security in Winforms as it is webforms

Tags: c#, winforms, security

I am creating an application in c# in which I want to give certain rights to admin and some to users. Since admin is the main owner so he has rights to access any user profile and alter it according. I knew that both have different login but how can I restrict the access for the user without altering anything without rights?

Any ref links or sample code in this regard will be highly obliged.

Answer (score 3):

The principal / identity model is still present, so you can use `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("myrole")`, or (above methods) `[PrincipalPermission(Role="myrole",Action= SecurityAction.Demand)]`, etc. In VS2008 you can hook the identity/principal directly into an ASP.NET authentication module (look for ["client application services"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx)), but it is fairly easy to write your own principal too, or use windows groups.

The good thing about "principal" - the abstraction means the same model works everywhere; WCF, winforms, webforms, asp.net mvc, etc.